# Best method to work with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, user-interface, methods, command

I am new to sql server, Which method is best to work with sql server COMMAND LINE OR GUI.

Comment: Command Line for repeatability.  GUI for daily "ins and outs".  See : http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2008/01/30/three-rules-for-database-work.aspx

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean "work with"?

I would say that that Microsoft SQL Management Studio, should be more than sufficient for anything you want to do. Using this should almost make any task relatively simpler than using CLI.

Comment: My friends ask me CLI approch is best to work with sql server. experts prefer to work with cli . can i contact with you for further help ?

Answer (score 1):

For regular usage, I use the GUI interface.  It has access to everything I need to do within one or two clicks. For automation tasks, or to interact with the service when the GUI is hanging, I use the command line.